# Making sense of partition tables

Tags: partitioning

This is output of `fdisk`:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   419424255   209711104   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       419424256  1258291199   419433472   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      1258291200  1300236287    20972544    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4   *  1300236288  1709836287   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5      1258293248  1275062271     8384512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

And this is output of `cfdisk`:

```
Name         Flags       Part Type   FS Type           [Label]         Size (MB)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                     Unusable                               1.05  *
sda1                      Primary    ext4                              214744.18  *
sda2                      Primary    ext4                              429499.88  *
sda5         NC           Logical    swap                                8586.79  *
                          Logical    Free Space                         12889.10  *
sda4         Boot         Primary    ntfs                              209715.20  *
                                     Unusable                          124768.71  *
```

I am supposed to have 2 Linux partitions, 1 Windows partition  extended partition of about 20 GB with logical 8GB swap partition and about up to 130GB un-partitioned space.

As if it wasn't enough, output of `gparted` is also kind of different.
[image]

I am confused from the outputs which I posted here.

1. Why is `/dev/sd4` marked as bootable if I boot to GRUB2?
2. What is /dev/sda3? What is its type (primary/logical)? Why it is not displayed in `cfdisk`?
3. Why is that free space (I suppose 124768 in `cfdisk`) marked as unusable?
4. What does NC flag mean in `cfdisk` for swap partition?

Answer (score 26):

## Why is /dev/sd4 marked as bootable if I boot to GRUB2?

The bootable is a flag in the MBR (actually a byte which is compared to 0x80). That entry is marked as bootable. A 'traditional' bootloader reads the MBR, looks for an entry with the bootable flag, and passes control to it. As you are using grub, it does something completely different, as it instead uses its configuration file. But the tools are telling you how are partitions *configured* (actually, you may have a bootloader in the MBR jumping you to /dev/sda4, and grub2 installed there).

## What is /dev/sda3? What is its type (primary/logical)? Why it is not displayed in cfdisk?

/dev/sda3 is a *primary partition* of type *extended partition*. It's a partition used as container for other partitions. gparted is showing it quite well on its graphic.

You could argue if it's actually a partition or not, on the one hand it takes a slot in the MBR, on the other hand it's a *container of partitions*, you don't put a filesystem there.

Partition tools treat them specially, so cfdisk seems to prefer not to show it. fdisk for instance also doesn't allow some actions on those partitions.

## Why is that free space (I suppose 124768 in cfdisk) marked as unusable?

I think those are the 116.20 GiB showed by gparted at the end

You can only have up to 4 primary partitions (counting the extended partition). That comes from the number of *slots* at the end of the MBR. As you already have 4 of them, that unallocated space at the end can't be partitioned (you can't put a logical partition there, since you can only have a single extended partition, and it shall be contiguous).

Your (easy) options to use that space would be to either:

- extend /dev/sda4 to use it
- extend /dev/sda3 to include /dev/sda4 (and preferably also to the end of the disk) and make /dev/sda4 a logical partition

## What does NC flag mean in cfdisk for swap partition?

Quoting the [cfdisk man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/cfdisk.8.html): *"The flags can be Boot, which designates a bootable partition, or NC, which stands for "Not Compatible with DOS or OS/2"."* Not something to worry about

Answer (score 11):

Let's start out...

1. It's marked as bootable, so that Windows can load its boot loader from it. Even though Grub may load first, it will "chainload" into the Windows boot loader, if Windows is selected from the list.  For the Windows Bootloader to run, it needs to be on a bootable partition (Could someone double check this for me? I've never tried removing the Bootable flag on a Windows 7 install...)
2. SDA3 is actually an [Extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition)  partition. Your disk is formatted as [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), instead of [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). One of the restrictions is that MBR can only have [up to 4 primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning). To get around this, you can use an Extended primary partition, to then create multiple smaller logical partitions inside (getting you more than 4 partitions).
3. Because of the MBR limitation, it can't create a 5th primary partition *outside of the Extended Logical partition*. This is normal. If you extend the Extended Partition, then you should be able to create a new partition inside of it, and use the rest of your disk.
4. From the [cfdisk Man pages](http://ss64.com/bash/cfdisk.html):

> The flags can be *Boot*, which designates a bootable partition or *NC*, which stands for "Not Compatible with DOS or OS/2".

Comment: No problem.  I was posting the same answer(s), and that one was the only one that you didn't nail down better than me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Partitions 1 to 4 are by convention "physical" (they were the only type available back in the times). So you have:

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   419424255   209711104   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       419424256  1258291199   419433472   83  Linux
/dev/sda3      1258291200  1300236287    20972544    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4   *  1300236288  1709836287   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda5      1258293248  1275062271     8384512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

...`sda1` is physical, Linux. `sda2` is physical, Linux again. `sda3` is a *logical partition* where *other* partitions (5 onwards) may reside. Finally `sda4` is a Windows partition, marked bootable - I think only Windows cares for that anymore. GRUB2 will gladly boot whichever partition you desire, but Windows wants to be on a bootable partition.

Now, **inside** the logical partition `sda3`, that `cfdisk` does not show as such, there are the equivalent of more physical partitions. In this case only `sda5`.

And since `sda3` goes from sector 1258M to sector 1300M, but `sda5` only uses them up to 1275M, sectors 1275062272 to 1300236287 are free (but allocatable to `sda6`).

Finally, your `sda4` (the last possible physical partition - the MBR only holds four) does not fill up to the end of the disk. It leaves about 116Gb off. That space is **unusable** because you cannot create a physical partition to cover it (the extended partition `sda3` can't grow, because its extent is "blocked" by `sda4`):

```
[SDA3...(sda5)...| FREE    ][...sda4...][ UNREACHABLE SPACE ]end-of-disk
```

## Solutions to recover the unavailable space

None painless, I'm afraid. Depending on the geometry, you could delete `sda4` and annotate its boundaries. Then grow `sda3` to include the whole disk (same start, 1258291200, but end up to the end of the disk), or delete it and recreate with same start and maximum end. Now you can create a partition `sda6` inside `sda3`, and make it so it ends at the cylinder just before sector 1300236288. This will occupy the free space currently left in the existing `sda3`. Finally you create a partition inside `sda3`, and it will be `sda7`, telling the system it extends from 1300236288 to 1709836287 and is type 7.

If you do not format that partition, the contents will remain as it is, and it is a valid Windows partition. It is

Of course if things go wrong, you stand to lose all of your data. Physical partitions (as the Windows one is now that is `sda4`) and physical-inside-logical partitions (as it would be once it became `sda7`) do not necessarily mix; some tools will flat refuse to create them. I'd suggest making a test on a virtual disk of the same size, created inside a sparse file (the file itself would really be only a few gigabytes) or on an external disk.

Another way, maybe safer, is to delete `sda5` (it's just swap) and `sda3`, move `sda4` parameters to `sda3` (this may imply deleting `sda4` and recreating `sda3` with the old `sda4`'s parameters), and this will leave the `sda4` slot free (and a "hole" in the middle of the disk). Most BIOSes allow for out-of-sequence partition tables. Again this should not require copying anything. `sda4` now becomes `sda3` and remains a physical partition, so its geometry should better agree with a partitioning tool's assumptions.

Of course the **recommended** and safest way (and slowest) of all is to backup *all* the partitions, reformat them *all*, and restore them after having "repositioned" them properly, with the extended partition last and occupying the whole remaining hard disk. This will get rid of the free space inside sda3 and reclaim the unavailable space at end, with no risks (if the backup is done properly - check it after backing up. I once backed up on a faulty external disk, which died on me upon restore. Wasn't amusing at all).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already said about the meaning of all this, I think the most painless solution would be to have the swap space in the big area at the end and to add the empty space in the middle to your `/home`.

To do so, you have to

- delete your swap file as soon as it is unused, and as well the extended partition holding it
- extend your `sda2` to include the complete empty space after it (you'll have to delete and recreate it).
- recreate the extended partition to sit after `sda3` and use it to hold as many partitions as you want (well, within certain limits).

This is most easily done with `cfdisk`, as it handles the extended partition dynamically. But take care that `sda2` keeps its starting LBA, as otherwise you will lose its contents.

After extending the partition size, you have to resize the file system enclosed to make use of the full space.